# Adding NSArrays to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, xml-parsing

I am parsing a XML file with a format of:

**NOTE: This is a very simplified version of the XML. There are 11 divisions, and 87 departments total

```
<division>
    <name> Sciences </name>
    <departments>

        <department>
            <name> Computer Science </name>
        </department>

        <department>
            <name> Biology </name>
        </department>

        <department>
            <name> Chemistry </name>
        </department>

    </department>
</division>
```

What I am hoping to do is display this info in a UITableView, with Division names as the Sections, and the department names within each appropriate section.

I have a NSDictionary called divisionDict which I want to store NSArrays for each division; containing the departments. I also have a NSMutableArray called departmentArray, which contains each of the departments. So essentially, I want a divisionDict filled with departmentArrays.

Here is my code for parsing the XML, which works perfect, I am just having trouble storing separate arrays in the dictionary. When it goes through the parse now, and I try to print out the elements in the array with key "Sciences", it prints the departments for every division, not just the Sciences.

```
if(node_divisions)
{
    node_division = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"division" parentElement:node_divisions]; 

    while (node_division) 
    {
        node_divisionName = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"name" parentElement:node_division];];
        node_departments = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"departments" parentElement:node_division];
        node_department = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"department" parentElement:node_departments];
        divisionName = [TBXML textForElement:node_divisionName];
        while(node_department)
        {
            node_departmentName = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"name" parentElement:node_department];
            departmentName = [TBXML textForElement:node_departmentName];
            //add the department name to the array
            [departmentArray addObject:departmentName];

            node_department = node_department->nextSibling;
        }
        //add the departmentArray to the dictionary, using the division name as the key
        [divisionDict setObject:departmentArray forKey:divisionName];;
        node_division = node_division->nextSibling;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!! I know its something simple I am missing probably but I have been looking at this for too many hours now and I just can't see it. If you need any other info, just let me know, I tried to explain everything in detail.

Also, here is a picture that hopefully helps show what I am trying to describe:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9nSb.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're adding all of the departments for each division to the same array.  I think you just need to create a new array for each division in the loop:

```
while (node_division) 
{
    departmentArray = [NSMutableArray array]; //add this line
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew that I needed to create a new array each time but my head is so fried I couldn't think..

Comment: @Ryan Garchinsky: You guys keep the habit of upvoting while you accept an answer, if it really helped you.

Comment: Check the other places that you're using divisionArray.  Either you're assigning a string as the divisionArray, or the array is being released too many times.  Maybe when you create the divisionArray, you're using something like [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:], without retaining it?

Comment: I have divisionArray being populated after the Parsing above with the line: divisionArray = [divisionDict allKeys];. If i print the count to the log right after I fill it, it prints out the right number, but when I use the count method in the number of sections method I get the error, that's what is puzzling me. The only thing i can think of is that [divisorArray count] is note returning a NSInteger. I have tried to cast it as one but still a no go.

Comment: @Ryan Garchinsky: Try `divisionArray = [[divisionDict allKeys] retain];`

Comment: @Simon That worked! It now works in the simulator... BUT I then went to test it on my iPod Touch and all the sudden I get: warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found). As well as an EXE_BAD_ACCESS which points to a line in TBXML.. Earlier yesterday I tested on my device and it worked fine; and it works 100% on the simulator. I have looked for fixes for the symbols junk and none of those solutions are working..

Comment: I resolved those issues. I have the tableView set up with the divisions as sections, and I have it displaying the correct about of rows per section (departments). Now I am trying to display each of the department names in the appropriate cell, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but I am stuck on how to implement this within that method. I know I must get the array of departments for each section and then go through that, setting the cell text, but once again this is just confusing me.

Comment: @Ryan Garchinsky: I suggest you to ask this as question as separate post. you will get more answers from others too. You will get best solutions. cheers..